# Optimal memory settings for JBOSS Server for using in a development machine

Tags: jboss, seam

For a seam project with EJB3, which is the optimal memory settings for a development machine(2Gb RAM with eclipse as IDE)?
How we can remove the unwanted services using eclipse?

Comment: you should really upgrade to 4GB, this will save you hours of twiddling.

Comment: More importantly. You should add more memory to jboss (if that is your app server)

Answer (score 0):

Run JBoss with the following set of JVM parameters

-Xms128m -Xmx512m
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xverify:none

You should not get memory-related exceptions and errors then. The 2GB memory limit should not be a big problem, however 4GB would give you more comfort.